# Data not passing from Controller to View Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am puzzled because of CodeIgniter's strange behavior. I am fetching some data from Model and returning it to Controller and passing that data from Controller to View.

**Controller**

```
function index()
    {
        $data['details'] = $this->Mymodel->Get_Details();
        $this->load->view('mypage',$data);
    }
```

**Model**

```
public function Get_Details() 
    {
        $query = "
                    SELECT 
                            *
                    FROM 
                            tablename
                 ";

        $result = $this->db->query($query)->result();
        return $result;
    }
```

**View**

```
<?php 
 print_r($details); 
?>
```

The problem is nothing is displayed in view page. If i give `print_r($data);` in `Controller` or `print_r($result);` in `Model`, the result is shown. If in `select`, `*` is replaced with individual column names then the output is passed from `Controller` to `View` and output is shown.
By any chance is there any limit to passing data from controller to view?

**Update:**In view if i use `print_r($details[0]);` or `print_r($details[n]);` the result is printed. If `print_r($details);` is used then page is just blank. What could be the problem?

Comment: are you sure it prints in the controller ? and if so make sure your view in the root of the view folder

Comment: @AhmedD.Sherif: I am quiet sure it prints in the controller. Why its not passed to view puzzles me.

Comment: Have you loaded your model?

Comment: @Catfish: yes! Have checked it also.

Comment: Then why don't you try to do a `print_r` in your model and in your controller to see if the data is getting that far even?

Comment: Which URL are you accessing? base_url/mypage or base_url (index page)?

You could try adding these to your controller:
    
    protected $view_data = array();
    $this->view_data["details"] = $this->Mymodel->Get_Details();

Comment: Your example is extremely simple and should work fine (based on the code posted here). It's probably something stupid like you modified the wrong view, or a route is not loading the controller in question. Unless you want to provide the actual code, it's difficult for us to diagnose. (And all the answers below are just different ways of producing the exact same results you're already getting.)

Comment: @Catfish: I tried as you suggested and data is getting printed when i use print_r in model or controller

Comment: @Cryode: What puzzles me is that instead of select * if i use select id or select columnname the result is printed in view. This problem arises only when i give select * . I have also tried select colname 1,colname 2,colname n to check if there's any problem data inserted in any particular column, since select * selects all the column. The output was printed.

Answer (score 0):

try this in the model

```
public function Get_Details() 
{
    $query = "
                SELECT 
                        *
                FROM 
                        tablename
             ";

    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    return $result->result();
}
```

Comment: Isn't that code equivalent to the code already in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code :

**Model**

```
    public function Get_Details() 
    {
        $query = "
                    SELECT 
                            *
                    FROM 
                            tablename
                 ";

        return $this->db->query($query);
    }
```

**View**

```
<?php 
 print_r($details->result()); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The result() function returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure.

You will need to loop through it in your view to get the expected results.

You can look here for details: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html